# Unexpected token, expected "," Eslint Typescript with Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I was getting this eslint error when trying to use vue's type assertion. here's an example:

```
data: function () {
        return {
            sellerIdToListings: {} as any, // 'as' Unexpected token, expected "," 
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started putting packages that didn't come with vue-cli 1 by 1 until I realized the **problem was with babel-eslint**. After removing it from package-json and unparse it from eslintrc the problem was solved